# How to get GUI same as Veriticall direction or in Horizantal direction?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I developed a application. In that i get GUI perfect in portrait, but when i tern my emulator(pressing Ctrl+F11) some text and buttons will be miss ordered. i searched so many sites but i am not get the solution.

Please any one give a solution.

Thank You.

Comment: Its difficult to imagine your code, rather paste your code, so that we can help you out. :)

Comment: Have you created a new layout for when vertical the phone is placed vertically?

Answer (score 1):

For solving these problem you should make two layout for different different
1-: create a new folder in side the resource is **layout-land** then put your layout for landscape in this folder.
2-: another one is use for portrait mode its put in layout folder.

Comment: yes. i got veriticall screens to horizantally using layout-land . but in layout-land  the screens will be compressed and bottom items are compressed. what can i do for get veriticall screens looks like horizantally.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your application to support landscape mode by creating different layouts.
simply you can create a folder in your res folder like this -> /res/layout-land and copy your layouts and make necessary changes(for landscape) to it.

please read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for further details

[tutorial](http://www.tekkie.ro/quick-n-dirty/how-to-change-your-layout-in-android-landscape-portrait-mode/)